# Add Symbol property to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-symbol

I want to add some metadata to an array, like a tag, but not actual data.

Say I have a symbol like:

```
const s = Symbol('foo')
```

Say I declare an array like so:

```
const v = [1,2,3];
```

is there a good way to tag the array with the symbol? Obviously adding it as a property might work:

```
v[s] = true;
```

I assume that this wont break anything and when the array is traversed the symbol property will never be hit? dunno!

**Update**: when I do this:

```
console.log(v);
```

I get:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, [Symbol(foo)]: true ]
```

but when I do:

```
v.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

I just get:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: It's fine. Normal iteration using `for...in`, `for...of`, and static `Object` methods specifically for string properties will not access the symbol property. However, what is the use-case for this? Note that `Symbol` is not very portable since transpiling to ES5 causes significant runtime overhead in order to polyfill properly. The reason I bring this up is that there's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also be aware that symbol properties are [not hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols), and that they are not copied when doing `map`, `filter`, `concat`, ...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts adding metadata as fields, without adding data

Comment: @trincot I am having trouble determining what you mean by "not hidden", they seem to be hidden for all operations except when reading the property directly by having a reference to the symbol itself.

Comment: Did you visit the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that this wont break anything and when the array is traversed the symbol property will never be hit?

Yes, neither iteration nor enumeration (which you [shouldn't do on arrays anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)) will hit the symbol. The only way to access the symbol is [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols).

`console.log` is just trying to be helpful for debugging purposes. It's not something you would need to hide from.

Comment: yeah I guess symbols are non-enumerable props by default - when you use console.log it will look for all props, including non-enumerable ones?

Comment: @rakim Symbols actually are ["enumerable"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31029612/1048572), but they still don't get enumerated by `for … in` or `Object.keys` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` because those look for string-named properties only.

Comment: @rakim And yes, `console.log` uses the debugger inspection view that exposes simply everything. Sometimes even things that are completely inaccessible to code, e.g. on closures or WeakMaps.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, it certainly won't. `for (const symbol of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(o))` already perfectly fills that niche.

Comment: @Bergi that's like saying `for (const key of Object.keys(o))` is a suitable replacement for `for (const key in o)`. The point is lazy iteration, whereas `getOwnPropertySymbols()` returns an array instead of an iterator.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True, although doing it non-lazily is probably better for loop performance anyway. And I've never really needed a lazy iteration (iterating over properties that were added during the loop?) so I doubt the ES committee would add new syntax for this.