# Why is a Symbol as an index value omitted when iterated?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, enums, iteration

I do follow [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44447975/5008962) to create an Enum(-like) structure in JavaScript with a Symbol:

```
const DATA = Object.freeze({
    GOOD:         Symbol("good"),
    BAD:          Symbol("bad"),
    I_DONT_CARE:  Symbol("i-dont-care"),
});
```

Now, I want to create a new object using the (unique) symbols to refer to each item and extend data about it:

```
const TRANSLATION = Object.freeze({
    [DATA.GOOD]:         "Gut",
    [DATA.BAD]:          "Schlecht",
    [DATA.I_DONT_CARE]:  "Egal",
});
```

This is indeed valid [even though e.g. TypeScript did not believe that and complained](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24587), but this is being fixed too.

However, the problem now is that if I do `Object.entries(TRANSLATION)` (or `Object.keys(TRANSLATION)` / `Object.values(TRANSLATION)`) to further edit and convert that object, I do get an empty object.

It seems all `Symbols` are ignored when iterating:

```js
myenum = {
  "bla": "blub",
  [Symbol("test")]: "testData"
}
console.log(Object.keys(myenum));
```

I do not want that, I just want to use the symbols as unique keys, so I can store/"map" more information to a specific entry.

Comment: That's the way those methods are defined to work.

Comment: It's sort of for consistency. Pre-ES6 we had `Object.keys` but not symbols, so `Object.keys(obj)` would have to work *differently* in ES5 and ES6, which makes the code unstable. `Object.entries` was added later than that, however if it iterated over symbols it would be inconsistent with `Object.keys`. There is `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` to extract only the symbols or `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` for everything.

Comment: Also, there is `Reflect.ownKeys` (I keep forgetting about `Reflect` as I don't use it often).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Symbols are not enumerable in for...in iterations. In addition, Object.getOwnPropertyNames() will not return symbol object properties, however, you can use Object.getOwnPropertySymbols() to get these. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

It's how Symbols work. They won't be iterated over. So using `Object.keys()` will exclude them from the result.

However you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) to get the Symbols from the object and then combine them with `Object.keys()` to create a definitive list of all keys.

Check the example below to see it work. Do note that the stack snippet console interprets the `Symbol` as `null`. However when you open the console of your browser you should see the result as it actually is.

```js
const myenum = {
  "bla": "blub",
  [Symbol("foo")]: "bar",
  [Symbol("roger")]: "roger"
}

const iterableKeys = Object.keys(myenum);
const symbolKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(myenum);
const keys = [...iterableKeys, ...symbolKeys];

console.log(keys);

const values = keys.map(key => myenum[key]);

console.log(values);
```

And as a shorter alternative which VLAZ suggested using `Reflect.ownKeys`

> Its return value is equivalent to Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target).concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(target)).

Which means it already combines the `Object.keys()` (but using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`) and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` by default.

```js
const myenum = {
  "bla": "blub",
  [Symbol("foo")]: "bar",
  [Symbol("roger")]: "roger"
}

const keys = Reflect.ownKeys(myenum);

console.log(keys);

const values = keys.map(key => myenum[key]);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Symbols are not iterated over. From my point of view they are more useful for hiding properties and generating unique re-used values.

I'd recommend using the TypeScript implementation, I think it's been iterated and battle-tested.

TypeScript has enums support:

```
enum Direction {
  Up = 1,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}
```

And it get's [transpiled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIglgJ2AYwC5wPYigbwFBRQCqADlALxQCMANAbBgO4h2EAywAZqq1AEpwA5gAseeAL5A) to the following JS:

```
var Direction;
(function (Direction) {
    Direction[Direction["Up"] = 1] = "Up";
    Direction[Direction["Down"] = 2] = "Down";
    Direction[Direction["Left"] = 3] = "Left";
    Direction[Direction["Right"] = 4] = "Right";
})(Direction || (Direction = {}));

// resulting object 
// Direction = {
//   1: "Up",
//   2: "Down",
//   3: "Left",
//   4: "Right",
//   "Up": 1,
//   "Down": 2,
//   "Left": 3,
//   "Right": 4
// }
```

If you switch from Symbol to unique strings the problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, okay, the reason is: Symbols are not [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). Fortunately, there is **[`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols)** that at least returns an array of all Symbols, similar to `Object.keys`.

With that, you can of course also "emulate" more advanced features like `OBject.values` in the oldish pre-ECMAScript 2017 way:

```js
const myenum = {
  "bla": "blub",
  [Symbol("test")]: "testData",
  [Symbol("goodsymbol")]: "baddata"
}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(myenum).map((mysymbol) => {
  const value = myenum[mysymbol];
  return [mysymbol, value];
}));
```

Comment: Corrections symbols *are* enumerable. However, they aren't iterated over. [The enumerable property is still taken into account in different cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029612/why-can-es6-symbol-properties-be-made-enumerable-by-object-defineproperty).

Comment: Also, if you want to iterate over all keys, I'd suggest `Reflect.ownKeys(myenum)`. It also happens to be shorter.