# Am I going to have performance improvement by using `Symbol` in my `action.type`?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

After I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724326/what-is-the-motivation-for-bringing-symbols-to-es6) while I am working on Reactjs. I have a question. Suppose I want to change `constants.jsx` from plain string to `Symbol()`.

**Question:**
Am I going to have any benefit from replacing `string` to `Symbol()` when I define `action` type?

If I do gain a performance benefit. How much percentage it improve?

Here is the sample of example

`constants.jsx`;

```
export const INCREMENT = 'increment';
export const DECREMENT = 'decrement';
export const ADD_COUNTER = 'add_counter';
export const REMOVE_COUNTER = 'remove_counter';
```

`reducers.jsx`

```
export const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return state + 1;
        case DECREMENT:
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected that a symbol alone is more costly than a string because strings are very fast and efficient in JS.

Usually a symbol includes a description because it's helpful, and the creation of `Symbol('increment')` symbol cannot be more efficient than `'increment'` string because symbol includes both a symbol and a string.

There generally should be no difference in performance after their creation, but this depends on the engine. Any way, both are very fast, and this concern is considered premature optimization and should be discarded unless proven otherwise.

On the other hand, practical considerations should be prioritized. Symbols could be helpful because Flux/Redux actions can suffer from collisions, and string values should preferably be unique; this can be solved with namespaces like `INCREMENT = 'foo increment'`.

Symbols cannot be efficiently used as actions for the reasons explained in [this Redux issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/4). They cannot be (de)serialized without special treatment - and even then there would be no guarantee because symbols should rely on description for their uniqueness, and descriptions are still strings. This may affect any third-party tools or libraries that don't support symbols as actions, e.g. [Redux DevTools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/142).