# Why do objects use `Symbol.iterator`, instead of just `iterator`

Tags: javascript

Do objects use the property `Symbol.iterator`, instead of just `iterator`, to prevent us from overwriting the `iterator` property on the Object prototype?

If so, are there any other reasons?

Just trying to understand symbols in JS.

Comment: Pretty good discussion and links here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724326/what-is-the-motivation-for-bringing-symbols-to-es6

Answer (score 3):

If it were just `iterator`, it could break old code that had objects with methods called `iterator`. Likewise, whenever the designers of JS want to let developers add other special methods to their objects, they would run the risk of clobbering existing names and breaking existing code.

An alternative is Python’s `__double_underscore__` convention where developers are not supposed to defined methods named like this.