# Is it possible to access the value of a Symbol in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, symbols

I have been just introduced to the concept of Symbols in JavaScript. I have been informed that they can be used to create unique identifiers to avoid potential clashes.

For example...

```
let user = {
    name        : "John",
    Symbol("id"): 123,    // Symbol("id") is a unique identifier
    Symbol("id"): 123     // and the Symbol("id") here is also different and unique
 };
```

... I understand the above code. However, what is the actual identifier value of each "Symbol("id")"? How do I find out?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by the value of the symbol? A symbol is just an object that has a name, and can be used as a unique identifier.

Comment: Are you asking how to go from `id1` to the string `"id"`?

Comment: @Barmar I am simply asking about the method that allows us to see the unique identifier contents. At the moment, I have been told that the identifiers are unique... But how can I actually view the contents to confirm?

Comment: `console.log(id1 == id2)` will say `false`, so you know they're different even though they both contain `id`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, thank you very much... I know about that already. However, I still want to be able to see the contents if possible... Is it possible?

Comment: You mean the internal identifier *maybe* used by the browser? Do you want to find this through web APIs or though some kind of debugger? The former is probably impossible, the latter... might be possible through a memory-dump? Will highly depend on your browser.

Comment: @Grateful You're thinking about it the wrong way, the Symbol itself is a unique identifier. There is no "content" or "value" that you can extract from it.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh really!? So there is no way of finding out about the actual contents of Symbol("id") through javascript?

Comment: There is no "content", it's just a Symbol by itself. Just like a number is just a number and two numbers even if they have the same value will be two different objects for the memory.

Comment: They're unique because they happen to be in different memory locations, just like two arrays that happen to have the same contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot see the "raw" value of the symbol in the JS environment, because it is implemented using the native C ++ code of the JS engine itself, and this implementation does not provide an opportunity to display it anywhere in the console or on a page.

You can think of symbols as big numbers and every time you create a symbol, a new random number gets generated (uuid). You can use that symbol (the random big number) as a key in objects.
Regarding this definition, you can look at a [possible implementation](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2013/03/simulating-es6-symbols-in-es5.html) of the symbol in ES5:

```
var Symbol;
if (!Symbol) {
Symbol = (function(Object){

// (C) WebReflection Mit Style License

var ObjectPrototype = Object.prototype,
    defineProperty = Object.defineProperty,
    prefix = '__simbol' + Math.random() + '__',
    id = 0;

//... some other code
```

You can see that *Math.random()* is used here, so Symbol there will have long big number as a his main property (unique with high possibility).

Another way to explain what a symbol is is that a Symbol is just a *piece of memory* in which you can store some data. Each symbol will point to a different memory location. In the context of this definition, you can see the source code in C++ of the JS engine itself, [for example V8](https://github.com/v8/v8) that is used in Chromium. If you know C++, you can try to find an implementation of Symbol() constructor there, but it won't be easy.

Therefore, we can say that a **Symbol** is a kind of **unique memory area** that a certain **string** describes. The memory area itself it's already term from a low-level programming, so you can think of it as something like 1010010011...

Answer (score 2):

```js
const id1 = Symbol("id");
const id2 = Symbol("id");

const user = {
    name: "John",
    [id1]: 123,    // "[id1]" is a unique identifier
    [id2]: 456,    // and the value of "[id2]" here is also different
};

console.log('id1:', user[id1], id1.description);
console.log('id2:', user[id2], id2.description);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. To be specific though, I am not talking about the values "123" or "456". I am talking about the actual identifier values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get your question properly, I tried to help you hope this will work

```js
let user = { // belongs to another code
  name: "Alex"
};

let id = Symbol("id");

user[id] = 200;

alert( user[id] ); // we can access the data using the symbol as the key
```

Answer (score 0):

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

> Every symbol value returned from Symbol() is unique.  A symbol value
>   may be used as an identifier for object properties; this is the data
>   type's only purpose.
>
> ```js
>  console.log(Symbol('foo') === Symbol('foo'))
> ```

From [an article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724326/what-is-the-motivation-for-bringing-symbols-to-es6):

> ES6 symbols are similar to the more traditional symbols in languages
>   like Lisp and Ruby, but not so closely integrated into the language.
>   In Lisp, all identifiers are symbols. In JS, identifiers and most
>   property keys are still considered strings. Symbols are just an extra
>   option.

As [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol#Symbols_dont_Auto-Convert_to_strings) explains, you could access the `Description` that you passed but not the value of the `Symbol`:

> Most values in JavaScript support implicit conversion to a string. For
>   instance, we can alert almost any value, and it will work. Symbols are
>   special. They don’t auto-convert.
>
> For example,
>
> ```js
> let Sym = Symbol("Sym");
> alert(Sym); // TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
> ```
>
> That’s a "language guard" against messing up, because strings and
>   symbols are fundamentally different and should not occasionally
>   convert one into another.
>
> If we really want to show a symbol, we need to call .toString() on it,
>   for example,
>
> ```js
>  
> let Sym = Symbol("Sym");
> alert(Sym.toString()); // Symbol(Sym), now it works
> ```
>
> Or we can use get symbol.description property to get
>   the description on it, for example,
>
> ```js
>  
> let _Sym = Symbol("Sym");
> alert(_Sym.description); // Sym
> ```